# Memory error when using Pandas built-in divide, but looping works?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, memory

I have two DataFrames, each having 100,000 rows. I am trying to do the following:

```
new = dataframeA['mykey']/dataframeB['mykey']
```

and I get an 'Out of Memory' error. I get the same error if I try:

```
new = dataframeA['mykey'].divide(dataframeB['mykey'])
```

But if I loop through each element, like this, it works:

```
result = []
for idx in range(0,dataframeA.shape[0]):
    result.append(dataframeA.ix[idx,'mykey']/dataframeB.ix[idx,'mykey'])
```

What's going on here? I'd think that the built-in Pandas functions would be much more memory efficient.

Comment: Do both dataframes have the same indices?

Comment: Genius! That's what the problem was. Forgot to `reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

@ayhan got it right off the bat.

My two dataframes were not using the same indices. Resetting them worked.